# Show that $ f : [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [a, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous, and $ f: [b, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is uniformly continuous.
Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.
Then, use this idea to show that $ f : [0, +\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$, is uniformly continuous

I understand that we can't use a theorem to show continuity on the whole domain, so instead we cut the domain into smaller portions to apply certain theorems. In the second part I can see why we need to cut up the interval into one which is closed and one which is bounded.

Comment: Use continuity at $x=b$ to join the two parts $[a,b]$ and $[b,+\infty)$

Comment: Your "universal epsilon" is the minimum of the two epsilons.

Comment: @user46944 yeah

Answer (score 1):

**For the first part(as requested):**

Consider $a<p<b<q<c$;

$|f(p)-f(q)|=|(f(p)-f(b+h))+(f(b+h)-f(b))+(f(b)-f(q))|$.

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$ so given $\epsilon>0$ we have $\delta_1>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $ whenever $|x-y|<\delta_1 $.

Also $f$ being continuous at $b$ so $|f(b+h)-f(b)|<
\epsilon $ whenever $|h|<\delta_2$

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[b,c]$ so given $\epsilon>0$ we have $\delta_3>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon $ whenever $|x-y|<\delta_3 $.

So $|f(p)-f(q)|=|(f(p)-f(b+h))+(f(b+h)-f(b))+(f(b)-f(q))|\le |f(p)-f(b+h)|+|f(b+h)-f(b)|+|f(b)-f(q)|$

Choose $\delta =\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2,\delta_3\}$

Then $|p-q|<\delta\implies |f(p)-f(q)|<3\epsilon$.

The proof is obvious when $a<p<q<b$ or $b<p<q<c$.

**For the 2nd part**

We show that $f(x)=\sqrt x$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$ using

1. $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$
2. $f(x) $ is uniformly continuous on $[1,\infty)$.

1.Since $f(x) $ is continuous on the  compact set $[0,1]$ hence $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$.

2.$|f(x)-f(y)|=|\sqrt x-\sqrt y|=\dfrac{|x-y|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}$;

WLOG let $x>y$; then $\dfrac{|x-y|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt y}\le \dfrac{|x-y|}{\sqrt x+\sqrt x}= \dfrac{|x-y|}{2\sqrt x}$

As $x\ge 1\implies \dfrac{1}{\sqrt x}\le 1$

So $\dfrac{|x-y|}{2\sqrt x}\le \dfrac{1}{2}|x-y|<\epsilon $ whenever $|x-y|<\delta $ and $\epsilon=\dfrac{\delta}{2}$

Comment: Technically you'd still need to prove that "pasting" uniformly continuous functions together carries over the uniform continuity property.  For example, take any $x <1$ and $y >1$ with $|x-y| < \delta$.  Your answer lacks the argument that $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: Also, I just read OP's full question.  What I pointed out in my last comment is exactly what they are trying to prove.

Comment: Yes, how would I prove the first part of my question?

Comment: @user381164;I have added an answer to the first part;Please check it

Answer (score 1):

Assume $0\leq x<y$ througout. Then
$$\bigl(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y-x}\bigr)^2=y+2\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y-x}\geq y\ .$$
This implies $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y-x}\geq\sqrt{y}$, so that
$$0<\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}\leq \sqrt{y-x}\ .$$
Given an $\epsilon>0$ we therefore can say that $0<y-x<\delta:=\epsilon^2$ implies $0<\sqrt{y}-\sqrt{x}<\epsilon$.